# ipod touch locked all the way cant get in at all

Tags: apple-id

I bought a ipod i tried contacting the owner i tried everything but there apple id and password is on the ipod i cant login or try to set it up for me becuase it says its linked to an apple id but the person i bought it from isnt answering my calls and i cant get in the ipod how do i get in it is there any other way????? any website ideas anything? i payed 200.oo i really need help geeting into the ipod a differnt way they basicly put find my iphone on the device

Answer (score 0):

You can erase your iPod in recovery mode using iTunes. This process will wipe out everything on the iPod including passwords. Here's a link to Apple's instructions.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204306

Scroll down to a little over half way to the heading: "Erase your device with recovery mode."

I had to do this with a used iPod I bought a few weeks ago.

Comment: This will result in the same lock - requesting the original Apple ID to activate the device after an erase operation.